# modulo - wrong order of operand by gcc? or UB?

Tags: c++, gcc, modulo

Well, i made a little function today which should generate me a little random string.

```
std::string randString(size_t length)
{
    std::string randStr;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        randStr.append(1, (char) rand() % 26 + 65);
    return randStr;
}
```

I expected to get only capital letters, but actually i got also other chars like '3' or ')' too. So i assumed there is some sort of order of operand error. And with parenthesis around the modulo i get the expected result! I extra searched for the order of operation of both modulo and addition and it says that modulo has higher priority!
Can anybody explain me why i have to parenthese this modulo?

I use gcc 4.1.2

Comment: Operator precedence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator %` has higher priority than `oeprator+`, BUT casting has even higher.

So, you have <strike>undefined</strike> implementation <sub>(thanks to @JamesKanze)</sub> defined behavior here, because there's an overflow of `signed char`.

You don't need to surround with parenthesis the "modulo" operator, but the casting, as you want to cast the final result: `(char)( rand() % 26 + 65 )`

Comment: okay and i have no overflow if i do the modulo beforehand, thats why i get the expected result. very interesting, thanks alot!

Comment: @PhilippMichalski - yes, exactly, just casting the final result would be more "readable" :) That's a bit tricky question, it took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: @KirilKirov Not undefined behavior, but implementation defined.  And even if it wraps (the most frequent behavior), the results of casting to a `char` may be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, type casting has a higher priority then the `%` and `+` (but lower than a function call), so the order here is:

```
rand()
((char) rand())
((char) rand()) % 26
(((char) rand()) % 26) + 65
```

**When unsure about operator precedence, always add brackets!** They don't hurt, but help to avoid such errors. To get the result you wanted, you should add brackets to make the type casting go last:

```
(char) (rand() % 26 + 65);
```

Here's a table for the reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: One more reason not to use C-style casts in C++ code. Even the semantically equivalent function-style cast `char(rand() % 26 + 65)` would have solved it, let alone `static_cast<char>( ::: )`.

Comment: oh damn, i totally forgot, that a cast is a operator too :-D thanks

Comment: When unsure about operator precedence, **look it up**. Unnecessary parentheses **do hurt**: at best they distract readers who know how the language works, and at worst they make readers suspicious of the writer's competence. Do you really want to wade through `((char)((rand()%26)+65))`?